# Unable to execute stored procedure but the update statement within the stored procedure works

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database that is currently replicated to three different locations. It is used for an application and all tables, stored procedures and articles are selected to replicate as well.

When I try updating the ContactCSR, through the stored procedure, I get the following error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure UpdateContactCSRs, Line 14
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ContactCSRs'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.ContactCSRs'. The duplicate key value is
>   (3443001, dand). The statement has been terminated..

The content of the stored procedure is the following:

```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateContactCSRs] @Contact int,
    @CSR varchar(50),
    @Memo varchar(max),
    @Notify bit,
    @OldCSR varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ContactCSRs SET CSR = @CSR,Memo = @Memo, Notify = @Notify WHERE Contact = @Contact  AND CSR = @OldCSR;
END
```

However, when I run the update command within the procedure it works.

Not entirely sure why this would be happening that the stored procedure doesn't work even though the update statement works.

Here is the Stored Procedure command that I am running:

```
exec UpdateContactCSRs 3443001, 'dand','Relationship Manager',1,'AndyK'
```

and Here is the update statement that I am running:

```
UPDATE ContactCSRs SET CSR = 'dand',Memo = 'Relationship Manager', Notify = 1 WHERE Contact = 3443001 AND CSR = 'AndyK'
```

Comment: Did you run the update command with exactly the same parameters as you tried with stored proc?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing in the same parameters to both the stored procedure and just the update statement? Basically when you are passing the statement through the application it may not be the same as when you run the update statement manually.

Comment: A primary key error means that the UPDATE you are doing, on of those fields has a constraint that requires it to be unique, and you are setting it to something that exists in the database already.

Comment: Neither of those are the cases. And if that is the case then the Update statement should not work either correct?

Comment: I've tried running the stored procedure through MSSQL and that's the error that I encounter.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the parameter names in the stored procedure call, do you still get the error?

```
exec UpdateContactCSRs @Contact = 3443001, @CSR = 'dand', @Memo = 'Relationship Manager', @Notify = 1, @OldCSR = 'AndyK'
```

Comment: That still does not work. I get the same error message. Is there something wrong with the Constraints, or the indexes for the table?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the constraint or the indexes, I think something is happening behind that sproc that you're not seeing. Execute the sproc and capture a trace as it runs (under the Query menu in SSMS, "Trace Query In SQL Server Profiler".

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working now. I made a change...but it seems as if it didn't get replicated so when I executed the command on the subscriber it failed. It works now.

Comment: However, I am getting a concurrency violation within the application now, even though the update command works. Any ideas as to why that would happen.